# fibonacci sequence printing wrong value

Tags: java

Implementation of fibonacci in Java:

```
 public class Fibonacci {

    private int fibonacci(int n){
        return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }

    private void test(){
        System.out.println(fibonacci(4));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fibonacci test = new Fibonacci();
        test.test();

    }

}
```

Using Oracle Java 8 on Ubuntu, it prints out 3 in Eclipse. But I was expecting 5:

```
                        fibonacci(4)
            fibonacci(3)                                 fibonacci(2)
      fibonacci(2)      fibonacci(1)            fibonacci(1)        fibonacci(0)
fibonacci(1) fibonacci(0)   1                      1                         1
    1            1
```

So then what's wrong with my Java implementation?

Answer (score 4):

Your `fibonacci(int n)` in Java will return 0 for `n=0`. You want to always return `1` for n<2. Replace:

```
 return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
```

with

```
 return n < 2 ? 1 : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
```

As it currently stands, the following is evaluated: (f is short for fibonacci)

```
f(4)
f(3)+f(2)
(f(1)+f(2))+(f(0)+f(1))
(1+(f(0)+f(1)))+(0+1)
(1+0+1)+(0+1)
2+1
3
```

The following *should* occur:

```
f(4)
f(3)+f(2)
(f(1)+f(2))+(f(0)+f(1))
(1+(f(1)+f(1)))+(1+1)
(1+1+1)+(1+1)
3+2
5
```

Comment: Yeah I see, the first one returns n rather than 1, where n could be 0. It was an oversight.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the language.

The first returns the sequence  0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 ...

The second returns the sequence 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 ...

It's up to you to decide which sequence you want.

Comment: @hexafraction actually, both are used. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Comment: Sorry about that, I only glanced at the sequence and thought I saw something else.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with the language. I just wanted to know why they were different output, obviously there something wrong with one of them.

Comment: @JohnMerlino See the link in my first comment. Both sequences are used.

Comment: Yes, and in addition to deciding which sequence you want, you also have to decide whether to call the first element F[0] or F[1] (i.e. fibonacci(0) or fibonacci(1)).